# Maximum-likelihood estimation for univariate responses from multivariate data

Tags: gaussian, estimation-theory, learning-theory

I am new in the field of machine learning, so I hope I will be able to formulate my question in a clear way...

I have some data represented by vectors $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n \in \mathbb{R}^m$, that is, each sample is a collection of $m$ features. In addition, I have a response corresponding to each data point: $y_1,\ldots,y_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to train a parametric model on this data, in order to be able to predict the probability density of the response $y(\mathbf{x})$ corresponding to a new sample $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$. (I really need to have a probability density for $y(\mathbf{x})$, not just a punctual estimation.)

So my idea would be to select a family of parametric densities defined through a parameter $\boldsymbol{\theta}\in\mathbb{R}^k$, $f(y;\boldsymbol{\theta})$. Then, I would like to run a maximum-likelihood procedure to find the best possible function $\theta$ from a class of functions $\Theta$ mapping $\mathbb{R}^m\mapsto\mathbb{R}^k$:
$$
\max_{\theta \in \Theta} \sum_{i=1}^n \log f(y_i,\theta(\mathbf{x}_i)).
$$

**Question 1**
Is this a well-studied problem, and if yes, how is it called in the litterature?
Or is there an alternative approach that is known to work better?

**Question 2**
My first, naive idea, is to restrict myself to a class $\Theta$ of linear functions, so the above problem reduces to determining $km$ coefficients.
In this case, any reference to some algorithm performing this task would be appreciated.

**Question 3**
If we consider a family of gaussians whose parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$
are linear functions of $\mathbf{x}$, i.e. $y \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\mathbf{x}, (\boldsymbol{\sigma}^T\mathbf{x})^2)$ for some 
vectors  $\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\sigma}\in \mathbb{R}^m$,
then the optimization problem to solve is
$$
\min_{\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\sigma}\in \mathbb{R}^m}\quad
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y_i-\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\mathbf{x}_i}{ \boldsymbol{\sigma}^T\mathbf{x}_i} \right)^2 + \log(\boldsymbol{\sigma}^T\mathbf{x}_i).
$$
What is the state-of-the-art to solve this problem ?

**Question 4**
If we assume that $f$ is a mixture of laws $f_1,\ldots,f_N$
defined by a vector of probabilities $\boldsymbol{\pi}$,
is there a way to construct a function $\pi$ that maps $\mathbf{x}$ to
the probability vector $\boldsymbol{\pi}=\pi(\mathbf{x})$, so that
the density of the response $y(\mathbf{x})$ is given by 
$
\sum_{j=1}^N \pi_j(\mathbf{x}) f_j(y).
$
I have the feeling that using a neural network might be appropriate to do construct the function $\pi$, but again, I would be gladeful if someone could point out a good reference for this specific problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would like the predicted variance to be as small as possible. So mybe it would be more appropriate to add a penalization term in the problem: $$\max_{\theta \in \Theta}\sum_{i=1}^n \log f(y_i,\theta(\mathbf{x}_i)) + \lambda \operatorname{var}[f(\cdot,\theta(\mathbf{x}_i))] $$

Comment: Maybe I'll look at this later, but for now I have this brief comment: finding the value of $\theta$ that maximizes the function you've got above is maximum-likelihood estimation, but it is not Bayesian (as suggested in your subject line). A purist might say "Bayesian" implies treating probabilities as epistemic rather than as being relative frequencies or proportions or the like. But even someone not so "pure" will tell you that you should consider prior and posterior probability distributions of $\theta$ before you call it "Bayesian".  Indeed, "maximum likelihood" would${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$usually be considered as contradicting the word "Bayesian." ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you Michael for this precision about the Terminology, I corrected the title of the question. I had the feeling that what I was intending to do was Bayesian, because I am looking for a density rather than a punctual estimation. But you're right, after all what I want to do is punctual estimation of the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: It seems that what I try to do is related to *Gaussian processes*. See my more detailled answer on [crossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172982/).